# Trouble when trying to define a make file to delete a file

Tags: unix, makefile

I've definde a makefile with the following contents:

```
mainmake: main.c
    gcc -o main main.c

clean:
    rm -f main
```

When running

```
make mainmake
```

it compiles main.c as expected with no problems, at all.

When I try to run

```
make clean
```

all I get is a

```
make: *** No rule to make target `clean`. Stop.
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: What version of make are you using?

Comment: is there a reason for not calling your main target 'main' ? if you use a different name, make will try to compile main each time, even though main.c hasn't changed

Comment: Check the output of `make -p`. Is there a description of the `clean` rule in there somewhere (near the end)? If not, something technical is wrong with your makefile. Does the line `rm -f main` start with a tab? Perhaps add a newline at the end of this line if there isn't one. Are there non-printable characters hidden somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `mainmake` rule?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following before the definition of the 'clean' target:

```
.PHONY: clean
```

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile works fine for me with GNU make 3.81 when the tabs are right. While @gregj correctly suggested that clean should be phony, the phonyness of a target shouldn't influence its remaking when no file named "clean" exists.

I assume that you got some tabs wrong. Check that tabs (not 8 spaces!) are in front of the gcc and rm lines, and add an empty line at the end in case your editor is broken and doesn't insert a newline at the end of the file.